# How to access data in JSON file in angular app

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to upload and parse a JSON file to an angular app. The problem is that I can get the file uploaded but I can't access data.

I've confirmed the proper file is being uploaded by checking bit size.

I'm quite confident the solution is quite simple but I've never worked with JSON in angular before. Below is my code the function where I am looking to access the file is `startUpload()`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';


interface User {
  email: string;
  store_name: string;
  username: string;
  uid: string;
  authToBuild: boolean;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})
export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {

    task: AngularFireUploadTask;

    percentage: Observable<number>;

    snapshot: Observable<any>;

    downloadURL: Observable<string>;

    isHovering: boolean;

    uid: any;

    authToBuild: boolean;

    userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;

    snapshotName: any;


  constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth, private storage: AngularFireStorage, private db: AngularFirestore) { 

    this.af.authState.subscribe(auth => { 
      if(auth) {

          //this.getAccountName();
          this.uid = auth.uid;
          this.userDoc = this.db.doc("users_real/" + auth.uid);
          //this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
          this.snapshotName = this.userDoc.snapshotChanges()
          .subscribe(event => {
            //this.name = event.payload.data()["name"];
            //this.authToBuild = event.payload.data()["authToBuild"];

            console.log(event.payload.data()["name"]);

          });




        }

      });

  }

  toggleHover(event: boolean) {
    this.isHovering = event;
  }


  startUpload(event: FileList){
    const file = event.item(0);

    console.log(file)




  }

  isActive(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.state === 'running'  && snapshot.bytesTransferred < snapshot.totalBytes
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: What you want to do? After upload you want to access same data or before upload you want to manipulate it?? or data which you have want to parse and upload??

Comment: Answering your question seems irrelevant to the topic at hand.  The code I want help with is in startUpload and I think my request is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into parsing a local JSON file: https://www.quora.com/In-JavaScript-how-do-I-read-a-local-JSON-file

If I understand correctly, you need to read the contents of a local file, in this example being a JSON file. This would entail using a FileReader to get the contents of the file and the parsing the JSON from the file. Another question is from here do you need to upload the manipulated `.json` file to AngularFireStorage, or will you just be setting data on a Firestore Document?

We are all very confused because you have a lot of AngularFire code, but this involves client side File Reading. AngularFirestore is meant for adding documents with JSON data into a collection and AngularFireStorage is meant for uploading and downloading files. Neither of which deal with client side manipulation of any local filetype.

Comment: I’m uploading a JSON file to firestore but I want to be able to manipulate the data beforehand.  I know how to make the documents and collections already.

Comment: Do you not just have a variable in your code of the JSON object you need to upload to firestore that you can manipulate beforehand? Or are you trying to set up some kind of import method that takes a large JSON file, manipulates the data, then uploads the data into a collection?

Comment: Firestore is not pure json you must manipulate it first.  But I have not asked about uploading to firestore I have asked about how to access the data in the file.  I would really love some help but this is the second time you have asked a question not related to the code I am asking for help with.  Please focus on my request not what you think my request should be.

Comment: First, I am trying to help by asking additional questions as your question is confusing and badly formed. Documents in Firestore ARE pure JSON and collections are JSONArrays of JSONObjects. This is why I asked if you are trying to get a local JSON file and parse the data in it and then upload to Firestore. You have not specified which file type you are accessing in the `startUpload` method and therefore makes it very confusing as to what the end goal is here, so thats why I continue to ask questions. I think you need to do some more research on Firestore and handling JSON Objects in code.

Comment: I do understand the confusion from my original answer, but I cannot help you if you can't answer the ensuing questions about your goal here.

Comment: Well the thing I've already uploaded the data parsed it and made it usable on my live firestore database, I need zero help with that.  I'm trying to create a different form of uploading it to my database for reasons that are unimportant to this question.  The issue I am having is that in startUpload I have the file but no access to its data.  If the question is about the file type then ask that, its .json btw.

Comment: Also while the documents are pure JSON unlike RTD the whole database is not.

Comment: I made EDIT 2 to hopefully give some direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172023/discussion-between-blue-and-nicholas-pesa).